# How to use my wcf services?

Tags: wcf, design-patterns

I’m working on a project where my class use a couple of wcf services. I use multiple test wcf services and multiple wcf services for production. I need to call may test wcf services when I have to use the test endpoints and I have to use the production wcf services when I have to use the production endpoints. The test wcf services and the production wcf services are equal.

Ex:

wcsServiceTest – endpoint: https://www.organization.testendpoint.com

wcfServiceProduction – endpoint https://www.organization.prodendpoint.com

Both of the services provides the functions getAllCats and getSingleCat

I want to be able to switch between the test services and the prod services when I call my functions that use this services. I thought about making a Factory class, and to classes who are similar to each other (have exactly the same functions) except from the imports of the wcfs. My Test class imports the test wcf services and my Prod class imports the prod wcf. My Test and Prod class will then share the same Interface but the problem is when I do it like this I have to import the endpoints in my interface. Then I have to import both the test wcf services and the prod wcf services in my interface.

Is this a good solution or is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something here, but why don't you use [Web.Config Transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and override the WCF endpoint accordingly?

So

- In your `Web.Debug.Config`, have the Endpoint for the Test Service Endpoint, and also any other Test-only AppSettings etc.
- In your `Web.Release.Config`, have the Endpoint for the Production Service Endpoint as a Transform directive, and also any other PROD-only AppSettings as Transform directives.

When you build and deploy, the `Web.Config` that will be generated will have the correct environment specific settings including the endpoints.

- See: [ASP.NET Web Deployment using Visual Studio: Web.config File Transformations.](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations)
- Also: [Slow Cheetah AddIn for Testing and Automating XML Transforms](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5).

With the **Slow Cheetah AddIn**, you can actually make Transforms and **Preview** them inside Visual Studio, so you can be sure the Transforms are getting applied when you do your Builds! Very neat feature IMO.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will look into that! This is probably the solution I was looking for :) Just a question, when I add my service references in VS under "Service references", I have to enter the service endpoint adress. How can I do that when my service have both a "test" and a "prod" adress?

Comment: When you say "add my service references" are you referring to the Client Application that is consuming the Service? If so, you should generate a Proxy and use the appropriate address that comes from Config instead of adding the "hard-coded" reference which generates a lot of un-necessary code behind the scenes.